# Несколько одновременных openvpn подключений на windows

Tags: openvpn

у меня есть удаленный сервер, на нем стоит OpenVPN server, на винде же стоит клиент, который к нему подключен. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы было не одно впн подключение, а два. В интернете везде написано, что нужно запускать addtab.bat из папки C:\Program Files\TAP-Windows\bin, а у меня не то что addtab.bat нигде нет, но и самой папки TAP-Windows. Как решить эту проблему?
Заранее благодарю

Все, что есть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала — вы уверены, что вам нужен именно tap, а не обычный tun?

Comment: @andreymal, не уверен. Я просто хочу, чтобы было два разных соединения для разных айпишников(например, для ютуба один впн, для вконтакте другой впн)